# Issue with AngularJS Base Controller and Modal Service Interaction

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am encountering a problem with my AngularJS base controller, specifically in its interaction with a function named `closeMyModal` provided by my `ModalService`. Initially, the base controller successfully recognizes and invokes this function, but later on, it seems to lose its reference to it.
However, when I encapsulate the call to `closeMyModal` within a trigger-dependent block, the base controller appears to lose awareness of the `closeMyModal` function.

It seems like the base controller loses its connection with `ModalService` in this context. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

BaseController code:

```
// BaseEditorController.js
var app = angular.module('myApp');

"use strict";

app.controller("BaseEditorController", BaseEditorController);

BaseEditorController.$inject = ["$scope", 'ModalService'];

// BaseEditorController.js
function BaseEditorController($scope, ModalService) {
    

    $scope.saveOrUpdateEntity = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior

        // Access the values entered by the user in the form
        var name = $scope.entity.Name;
        var gender = $scope.entity.Gender;

        // Perform save or update logic as needed
        console.log($scope.entity);

        // Close the modal and pass the added or edited entity
        $scope.closeMyModal($scope.entity);
    };
}



StudentService code:
// StudentService.js
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.service('StudentService', function (ModalService, StudentWebApiService) {
    var service = this;

    // Method for adding a new student
    service.addStudent = function (onStudentadded) {
        var modalInstance = ModalService.openModal('uib/template/modal/window.html', {
            entity: { Id: 1, Name: "Aya", Gender: 2 }
        }, function (result) {
            // result is the data passed from the modal when it is closed
            console.log(result);
            // Perform any additional actions here, if needed
            StudentWebApiService.addStudent(result.entity);
            onStudentadded();
        });
    };
});

ModalService code:
// modalService.js
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.service('ModalService', function ($uibModal, $rootScope) {

    var service = this;

    service.openModal = function (url, params, onCloseCallback) {
        var newScope = $rootScope.$new();

        newScope.parameters = params;

        newScope.closeMyModal = function (result) {
            modalInstance.close(result);
            newScope.$destroy();
            // Execute the callback function when the modal is closed
            if (onCloseCallback) {
                onCloseCallback(result);
            }
        };

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: url,
            controller: 'BaseEditorController',
            scope: newScope
        });

        return modalInstance;
    };

    return service;
});
```

Contrary to expectations, when the `closeMyModal` function is called within a block that depends on a trigger, the `BaseEditorController` appears to lose its reference to the function. This results in an error, suggesting that `$scope.closeMyModal` is undefined within that specific context.

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this unexpected behavior would be greatly appreciated.

[image: error display]